# Show that $(n+1)^3= O(n^3)$ by definition

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

## Show that following is true

Show that $(n+1)^3= O(n^3)$ by definition

## Attempt to show

By definition the mentioned statement is true when:

$$ \exists(c,n_0) : (n+1)^3 \ge cn^3 \text{ when } n> n_0 $$

let $n=1,n_0 = 0$, then we have

$$ (n+1)^3 \ge n^3 \text{ when } n > 1 $$

$$ \iff (n^2+2n+1)(n+1)-n^3 \ge 0 $$
$$ \iff n^2\cdot n + 2n \cdot n + 1 \cdot n + n^2 + 2n + 1 -n^3 \ge 0 $$
$$ \iff  n^3-n^3+3n^2+3n+1 \ge 0 $$
$$ \iff 3n^2+3n+1 \ge 0 $$

Then check when $3n^2+3n
+1 = 0$

$$ 3n^2+3n+1 = 0 \iff n = \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{3^2-4\cdot 3 \cdot 1}}{2 \cdot 3} $$

We notice that $3^2-4\cdot 3 \cdot 1 < 0$ which implies $3n^2+3n+1 > 0$ when $n \in \mathbb{R}$ which implies statement has to be true when $n > 1$

---

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems fine but it is easier to note that
$$
n+1\leq 2n
$$
for $n\geq 1$ whence
$$
(n+1)^3\leq (2n)^3=8n^3
$$
for $n\geq 1$ as desired.